# Ivy - get a flat list of modules and their revisions across multiple projects

Tags: dependencies, report, ivy, dependency-management

We use Ivy to manage our library dependencies and we need to create a report of all the modules and their revisions in certain configurations and combine this across about 30 projects. Just a simple list, no dependencies in it.

By "certain configurations" I mean that we e.g. use configurations "compile", "runtime", "test" in ivy.xml files and we only want to include "compile" and "runtime", since we are interested just in the list of libraries that actually ship with the product.

I'm familiar with the <ivy:report /> task and we use it to generate an HTML report for each project. Of course there is an option to use this output and parse it or use XSLT to achieve the desired report format. However, I'm wondering if there is any simpler way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [artifactreport](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactreport.html) task can be used to generate an XML file detailing the artifacts in a configuration:

```
<ivy:artifactreport tofile="build/runtime.xml" conf="runtime"/>
```

Here's a slightly different solution which combines [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) and the ivy [cachefileset](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachefileset.html) tasks to generate the Eclipse ".classpath" file based on the compile dependencies

```
<macrodef name="eclipse">
    <attribute name="srcdir"/>
    <attribute name="outputdir"/>
    <attribute name="classpathref" default="build.path"/>
    <attribute name="conf" default="compile"/>
    <sequential>
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="@{classpathref}"/>

        <ivy:cachefileset setid="libfiles" conf="@{conf}"/>

        <groovy>
        <arg value="@{srcdir}"/>
        <arg value="@{outputdir}"/>

        import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

        //
        // Generate the classpath file
        //
        // The "lib" classpathentry fields are populated using the ivy artifact report
        //
        project.log("Creating .classpath")

        new File(".classpath").withWriter { writer ->
            def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

            xml.classpath() {
                classpathentry(kind:"src",    path:args[0])
                classpathentry(kind:"output", path:args[1])
                classpathentry(kind:"con",    path:"org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER")

                project.references.libfiles.each {
                    classpathentry(kind:"lib", path:it)
                }
            }
        }
        </groovy>        
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```